# Auto focus on form text field .Focus() Me.show()

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want the browser to auto focus on the username text box when the login page loads for my vb.net web app- I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287605/cant-set-focus-on-a-windows-forms-textbox) answer on SO, and gave the accepted answer a try by adding calls to `Me.Show()` & `UserName.Focus()` in the `Page_Load()` function of my login.aspx.vb file:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(...) Handles Me.Load
    ...
    Me.Show()
    UserName.Focus()

End Sub
```

When I do this, `Me.Show()` throws a compile error stating that

> 'Show' is not a member of 'login'

If I comment that line, and run the application, the page loads, but the focus is not automatically set on the UserName box of the login form.

How can I get the app to automatically focus on this text field?

**Edit**

I tried doing this in the JS by adding the following to my login.aspx file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UserName').focus()
```

but again, when the page loads, the focus is not on the `UserName` textbox (there doesn't appear to be any focus on any of the page content).

As you can see from the screenshot below, `UserName` is the ID of the text box element that I'm trying to set the focus to:

[image: login]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.setfocus?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I gave that a go, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment because I haven't enought reputation, but if I understand correctly, you can do this in the JavasCript part:

```
document.getElementById('<%= UserName.ClientID%>').focus();
```

or you can try  `Form.DefaultFocus = "UserName";` in form_load event.

Comment: I tried adding the JS to my login.aspx file, with `$(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#UserName').focus() }`, but this doesn't seem to have made a difference...

Comment: Are you sure that on client the id of the Username control is "UserName"? could you verify with Chrome DevTools on Element tab? Or try with : $('#<%= UserName.ClientID%>').focus();

Comment: $('#<%=UserName.ClientID%>').focus(); sorry no space between = and UserName.ClientID

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the name of the `UserName` control is `UserName`- will upload a screenshot showing that.